# How do I modify a data structure and return it in OCaml?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

In a helper function, I am doing pattern matching to modify a data structure. I want to modify the data structure and then return the modified data. In my approach, the return type is unit(). I need it to return the modified hash_table.

I tried:

```
let helperfunction firstlist secondlist hash_table =  
    match(firstlist, secondlist) ->
        | (CUSTOMTYPE::tail, CUSTOMOBJA(a)::CUSTOMOBJB(b)::anotherTail) -> Hashtbl.add hash_table "key" (a+b); hash_table
```

and also,

```
let helperfunction firstlist secondlist hash_table =
 match(firstlist, secondlist) ->
     |(CUSTOMTYPE::tail, CUSTOMOBJA(a)::CUSTOMOBJB(b)::anotherTail) -> let aa = Hashtbl.add hash_table "key" (a+b); hash_table
```

None of them function as I wanted it to. My required functionality in a python-like language would be:

```
def helperfunction (HashMap hm, int ValueToBeAdded):
     hm.add("key", ValueToBeAdded)
     return hm
```

I am very new to functional programming.

Comment: Be it in Python or OCaml, mutating a data structure *and* returning it is very confusing. As a user of your function, the fact that it returns a data structure leads me to believe that it creates a fresh one and leaves the original unchanged, in a persistent fashion. For instance in Python, `li + [1,2,3]` is an *expression*, it builds a new value without any side effect, while `li += [1,2,3]` is (somehow) an *instruction*, it returns nothing (`None`) but has side effects.

Comment: For a more _functional_ approach, you may wish to investigate the [Map module](https://ocaml.org/api/Map.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hashtbl` are imperative (and mutable) data structure, so you don't need to return it, but if you want, you can. Your Python example can be translated, in OCaml in something like this:

```ml
let helper_function hash_table value_to_be_added = 
  let () = Hashtbl.add hash_table "key" value_to_be_added in 
  hash_table
```

Your second example is bad but I don't see any problem in the first (except the non-exhaustivity of the pattern matching).

Comment: Yes; it is why I say that "you can", and I give you an example. But if you have, in your scope the hash_table (that you pass to your function) the hash_table will be modified. For example : `let _ = helper_function hash_table 12 in Hashtbl.find "key"` will gives you 12, even you do not track the reference in your variable.